# words related to a topic (another word) using NTLK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

I'm working on building my own virtual assistant based on intent<->action mechanism and want to run some NLP on sentences that my users write.

I want to find out words related to a topic(another word) so that I can define an intent, for example:

If a user asks: Will it rain tomorrow? What's the weather today? is it sunny? Is if going to be windy this afternoon?

I want to be able to say that rain, weather, sunny, sun are related to the intent called weather so that I can communicate with the relevant API and retrieve the requested information.

I'm currently working with Python 3 and NLTK but using synonyms, path to parent and similarity doesn't really do the trick:

```
wordFromList1 = wn.synsets('weather')[0]
wordFromList2 = wn.synsets('cold')[0]
value = wn.wup_similarity(wordFromList1, wordFromList2)
print(value)
---------------------------
0.1
```

You can see that the similarity here for cold and weather is really weak. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: What's the programming question?

Comment: There's no easy answer here.  You can try comparing word vectors (ie.. GloVe) but you may have to manually program/train the system for this.

Comment: @bivouac0 By training the system, you mean something like neural network algorithm to incorporate machine learning in my program?

Comment: You could use regular-expression matching and include those similar words in the matcher, or you could use a neural net and include different sentences as training data with those words and map them to the same intent.  Note that with the NN approach you can use pretrained word vecs so you start out with some level of similarity baked in.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't use wordnet for this! it might be (very loosely) correlated to solving what you want but will yield horrendous accuracy and recall unless you engineer the hell out of it. For practical results what you need to do is look at things like LSA, LDA or word embeddings, something along those lines